# New Server - apache will not serve outside LAN

Tags: networking, server, apache2, firewall, iptables

New server, running well 12.04 LTS on HP ML350.

Apache = great, inside our LAN.
Apache = timeout, from WAN (NAT forwarded from firewall).

I have cleared all Iptables, read & checked every "allow" and "deny" in HTTP conf file & HTACCESS file.

With Iptables logging every packet, destination server sees the packet.
Rebooted firewall, tested firewall (all good) and DEFINITELY port forwarding to new server.

Rebooted server, cleared out iptables, checked all 4 MACs, NIC cards are good and working.
Static routing is 100% correct.

At a loss, all other 12.04 LTS servers are fine and configured just like this one.

Any help/pointers appreciated.

EDIT:

```
*Local Scan:*
Starting Nmap 5.21 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2013-06-04 22:46 BST
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00034s latency).
Not shown: 986 closed ports
PORT      STATE SERVICE
22/tcp    open  ssh
25/tcp    open  smtp
80/tcp    open  http
110/tcp   open  pop3
139/tcp   open  netbios-ssn
143/tcp   open  imap
443/tcp   open  https
445/tcp   open  microsoft-ds
631/tcp   open  ipp
993/tcp   open  imaps
995/tcp   open  pop3s
3306/tcp  open  mysql
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.06 seconds
```

```
*From another box inside LAN:*
nmap 10.0.0.33
Starting Nmap 6.00 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2013-06-04 22:47 BST
Nmap scan report for 10.0.0.33
Host is up (0.00030s latency).
Not shown: 987 closed ports
PORT      STATE SERVICE
22/tcp    open  ssh
25/tcp    open  smtp
80/tcp    open  http
110/tcp   open  pop3
139/tcp   open  netbios-ssn
143/tcp   open  imap
443/tcp   open  https
445/tcp   open  microsoft-ds
631/tcp   open  ipp
993/tcp   open  imaps
995/tcp   open  pop3s
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.12 seconds
```

```
*Remote Scan:*
nmap site1.FQDN -p 30333
    Starting Nmap 5.21 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2013-06-04 22:53 BST
    Nmap scan report for site1.FQDN (82.X.X.X)
    Host is up (0.033s latency).
    rDNS record for 82.X.X.X: ptr-X.X.X.82.rev.X.uk
PORT      STATE    SERVICE
30333/tcp filtered unknown
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.34 seconds

The request is: https:/warehouse1.FQDN:30333
This is getting firewall natted to "10.0.0.33:443".
```

```
I am starting to believe this is a hardware issue with the network cards on my LAN server, but any guidance appreciated.
```

Comment: Use **nmap** to do a port scan on the server itself `nmap localhost` then do a port scan from outside the LAN to see what ports are showing as open, if you like post the results.

Comment: Sorry could not fit it all into a comment - have added "EDIT" above.

Comment: The Server is stuffed!
Purchased second hand.
There is a fix. If I "sudo shutdown -r now", then the problems above are present.
If I abruptly hold the power, to force a shutdown, then reboot - everything works!
As mentioned, it is kaput.

Comment: Just fyi, you **nmap** from external should have been done on **all** ports not by specifying a port as unfortunately the above external port scan provides us with very little information, just for future reference :)